# getsku for simple product on configurable product view page

Tags: configurable-product, product-view

how can i display the sku from simple products on configurable product page?

i have tried:

```
$_product->getSku()

$item->setSku($product->getSku())

$simpleOption->getProduct($product)->getSku()

$simple->getSku()
```

Answer (score 2):

```
if($_product->getTypeId() == "configurable"):
    $conf = Mage::getModel('catalog/product_type_configurable')->setProduct($_product);
    $simple_collection = $conf->getUsedProductCollection()->addAttributeToSelect('*')->addFilterByRequiredOptions();
    foreach($simple_collection as $simple_product){
        echo $simple_product->getSku() . " - " . $simple_product->getName() . " - " . Mage::helper('core')->currency($simple_product->getPrice()) . "<br>";
    }
endif;
```

inspire from this. [here](http://www.tripleginteractive.com/blog/magento/magento-configurable-products-simple-product-data/)

Comment: did it worked??

Answer (score 1):

```
 /**
     * Get child products id (only ids)
    $childIds = Mage::getModel('catalog/product_type_configurable')->getChildrenIds($product->getId());

    /**
     * Get children products (all associated children products data)
     */
    $childProducts = Mage::getModel('catalog/product_type_configurable')->getUsedProducts(null,$product);

foreach($childProducts  as $childproduct ) {
    $childproduct->getSku();
}
```

above function is just sketch you can look for perfect function.

hope this will work for you.